# Excel OFFSET function with address string as reference value

Tags: excel, reference, return, cell, offset

I'm trying to use the =OFFSET function in Excel to return a value several columns/rows shifted from the reference value. However, I don't have a cell address to use as a the reference value - I have a cell containing a string value of the address. Ex:

Cell A1 value = "$B$11"   *(I'm getting this value with another formula, =CELL(address,index(match()))*

I want to use the literal string within cell A1 as the reference value for my offset formula.

Comment: Check [INDIRECT Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261). It's exactly whay you need

Comment: The `index(match())` returns a reference to the cell you want.  No need to go via the address string